# How to calculate column-wise variance sorting by another variable in R?

Tags: r, variance

I have a data frame in this structure, `Id` represents different people, and they are repeatedly measured in a variable called the `Intensity`.

Sample data:

```
Id    intensity
1     11
1     9
1     6
1     7
2     4
2     6
3     8
3     8
3     9
4     3
4     6
```

I want to calculate the variance of `intensity` for each `Id` in R, but I have no idea which function I should use. I visited few sites/googled for an answer, find nothing.

Could anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just, FYI, next time provide the sample data through `dput`, as then we get code, that yields the sample dataset in R.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base` R

```
aggregate(df$intensity, by=list(df$id), FUN=var)
  Group.1         x
1       1 4.9166667
2       2 2.0000000
3       3 0.3333333
4       4 4.5000000
```

By `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, id) %>% summarise(variance =var(intensity))
     id variance
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1    4.92 
2     2    2    
3     3    0.333
4     4    4.5
```

**Data**

```
df = data.frame('id' = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), 
                'intensity' = c(11,9,6,7,4,6,8,8,9,3,6))
```

Comment: @Yufei please consider putting "+1" and "accepting answer" if that helped you resolve the issue.